# Fetching data in codeigniter getting fatal error for dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter

Fetching data in codeigniter getting fatal error for dropdown.

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Blogs_model::where() in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\admin\application\models\blogs_model.php on line 32

Blogs:

```
function add()
{
    $data['categorylist']=$this->blogs_model->categories_dropdown();
    $data['mainpage']='blogs';
    $data['mode']='add';
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}

function addblogs()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error"> ','</span>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category_id','Category Name' , 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('blog_title','Blog Title');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Blog Description');
    if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)   
    {   
    $data['categorylist']=$this->blogs_model->categories_dropdown();
    $data['mainpage']='blogs';
    $data['mode']='add';
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this -> blogs_model -> insertblogs();
        $this->flash->success('<h2>blogs Added Successfully!</h2>');
        redirect('blogs');
    }
}
```

Blogs_model

```
function categories_dropdown()  
{       
    $this->table = 'category';      
    $this->where('status',1);       
    $categorylist=$this->dropdown('category_id','category_name');       
    return $categorylist;
}
```

View:

```
<div class="element">
    <label for="categoryname"><font color="black">Category Name</font></label>
    <?php
            $categorylist['']='--Select Category Name--';
            $category_id="id='category_id'";
            if($this->input->post('category_id')) $selected=$this->input->post('category_id');else $selected='';
            echo form_dropdown('category_id',$categorylist,$selected,$category_id);
            ?>
            <?php echo form_error('category_id', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?><br/><br/>     
    </div>
```

Comment: It's hard to say without full code of the `Blogs_model`, but it seems the line `$this->where('status',1); ` should be `$this->db->where('status',1);  `

Comment: @AlexanderPopov after adding $this->db getting this error as 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::dropdown()

Comment: Did you add `$this->db` to this line `$categorylist=$this->dropdown('category_id','category_name');`?

Comment: @AlexanderPopov problem solved in model i have given as  class Categories_model extends CI_Model so got the issue replaced CI_Model as MY_Model

Answer (score 0):

```
Please update your model as follows.

    function categories_dropdown()  
    {       

        $this->db->select('category_id','category_name');
        $this->db->from('category');
        $this->db->where('status',1);
        $result =   $this->db->get();
        return $result->result();

    }
```